# WARNING: kernel is not very fresh, upgrade is recommended

Tags: kernel, ping

Sometimes when running `ping`, I see the following:

```
$ ping somehost
PING somehost (192.168.x.x) 56(84) bytes of data.
WARNING: kernel is not very fresh, upgrade is recommended
```

What causes this warning, and can I ignore it? I'm actually running a relatively new kernel (3.5.0-17-generic).

Answer (score 2):

You can just ignore it, as per 
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=120166

Comment: Actually, telling someone in 2013 to ignore a warning and referencing a bug closed in 2002 is a weird thing to do…

Comment: Here is the 2013 bug report (and closed with a works-on-my-machine as well): https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=709052

Comment: @Damon: nope, it was closed as *fixed*, and changelog says `Silence erroneous "kernel is not very fresh" warnings. (Closes: 709052)`